# Subtraction of fractional exponents with different bases

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I wanna know if $$\left[(x^2+h)^3-(x+h)\right]^{1/2}-[x^3-x]^{1/2}=\left[(x+h)^3-(x+h)-x^3+x\right]^{1/2}.$$

Comment: want you to solve this?

Comment: The question is more about whether you can simply subtract two expression with the same fractional exponent and different bases

Comment: we can square the given expression

Comment: So I would have to first square the expression that would make the fractional exponent go  and then I can subtract without any problem ?

Comment: you must square two times

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does $a^2 - b^2 = (a-b)^2\;$?

No,  Because $$(a-b)^2 = a^2 -2ab +b^2 \neq a^2 - b^2$$
Alternatively $$a^{1/2} - b^{1/2} = \sqrt a -\sqrt b \neq \sqrt{a-b}$$
Simply take $a = 4, b = 9$.  Then we have $2 - 3 = -1$. Whereas $\sqrt{2-3}$ is undefined in the reals, and which will never be equal to a negative real number.

Answer (score 0):

after squaring two times and factorizing we obtain
$$x \left( x-1 \right)  \left( {x}^{10}+{x}^{9}+6\,{x}^{8}h+{x}^{8}+6\,{
x}^{7}h+15\,{x}^{6}{h}^{2}-{x}^{7}+9\,{x}^{5}{h}^{2}+18\,{x}^{4}{h}^{3
}-{x}^{6}-6\,{x}^{5}h-9\,{x}^{4}{h}^{2}+9\,{x}^{2}{h}^{4}-{x}^{5}-6\,{
x}^{4}h-15\,{x}^{3}{h}^{2}-18\,{x}^{2}{h}^{3}-9\,x{h}^{4}-12\,{x}^{3}h
-12\,{x}^{2}{h}^{2}-4\,x{h}^{3}-12\,{x}^{2}h-12\,x{h}^{2}-4\,{h}^{3}+4
\,xh+4\,h \right) 
=0$$
and now?

Comment: In what you just did, you introduce solutions when you square the original statement, and then square again.  For example, just looking at the summand $$(x^3 - x)^{1/2} = (x(x^2 - 1)^{1/2}.$$ Note that $x= \frac 12$ is not defined in the original.  But squaring it we get $x^3-x$, which is certainly defined when $x = \frac 12$.

Comment: can not read this sorry

Comment: Sorry, @Dr.SonardGraubner.  It's hard to see what how a comment with mathjax renders, until posting.  Hope you understand it now.

Comment: So, Dr., in the end, the answer to the question is "yes" or "no"? It is slightly disquieting that we cannot say from your post.